# Purpose of scaling disparity in stereo vision

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, disparity-mapping

This code calculates the disparity of two left and right stereo camera images ([github link to the complete code and used images](https://github.com/gaoxiang12/slambook2/tree/master/ch5/stereo)).

I do not understand why the disparity is scaled by (1/16) in `disparity_sgbm.convertTo(disparity, CV_32F, 1.0 / 16.0f);`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // 内参
    double fx = 718.856, fy = 718.856, cx = 607.1928, cy = 185.2157;
    // 基线
    double b = 0.573;

    // 读取图像
    cv::Mat left = cv::imread(left_file, 0);
    cv::Mat right = cv::imread(right_file, 0);
    cv::Ptr<cv::StereoSGBM> sgbm = cv::StereoSGBM::create(
        0, 96, 9, 8 * 9 * 9, 32 * 9 * 9, 1, 63, 10, 100, 32);    // 神奇的参数
    cv::Mat disparity_sgbm, disparity;
    sgbm->compute(left, right, disparity_sgbm);
    disparity_sgbm.convertTo(disparity, CV_32F, 1.0 / 16.0f);
```

Comment: From [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.9.0/d2/d6e/classcv_1_1StereoMatcher.html#a03f7087df1b2c618462eb98898841345): "Some algorithms, like StereoBM or StereoSGBM compute 16-bit fixed-point disparity map (where each disparity value has 4 fractional bits)" The scaling by 1/16 converts the fixed-point integer into a floating point number.

Comment: why? because you can. spatial lowpass (implicit in *block* matching because of the *blocks* not being pixels that couldn't be matched anyway) allows you to calculate subpixel-resolution estimates.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you. I did not know the output for disparity for this function could be non-integer. I believe the division by 16 is for converting a 16-bit fixed-point float with a 4-bit fractional part to a floating-point number, as the other person mentioned.